# Python/NetworkX/DiGraph: After simplification parallel connection of 2 nodes

Tags: python, networkx

given the following directedGraph (start at the red node --> direction from left to right): Through aggregation methods I can simplify the edges:

- Connection A, B, C to Connection 1
- Connection D, E, F to Connection 2

My question: After aggregation there should be a parallel connection of node 1 and 2 (through connection 1 and connection 2).

I read that MultiDiGraph can handle that problem - but since the whole project is based on DiGraph (and I read that it is not recommended to use MultiDiGraph if its not essential) I wanted to ask you if there is a work-around.

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve